# Check errors before function call or within function?

Tags: vba, excel

I am curious to know about what is considered to be the best method to check for errors before running a function. Is it best to make a check before the function is called or within the function itself?

For example, a simplified version of what I'm working on involves this Click subroutine:

```
Private Sub MyButton1_Click()
    For j = 1 to 3
        CreateChart Sheets(j)
    Next j
End Sub
```

Where the function it calls is defined like so:

```
Function CreateChart(Sht As Worksheet) As Boolean
    Set ChtObj = Sht.ChartObjects.Add(40, 40, 600, 300)
    Set Cht = ChtObj.Chart
...
End Function
```

I am dealing with code with multiple modules and many situations where certain checks need to be performed before the function can successfully run. Is it most appropriate to put a check within the loop in the Click sub routine, something like:

```
If DoesSheetExist(Sheets(j)) Then CreateChart(Sheets(j))
```

Or best to put it within the function like:

```
If Not DoesSheetExist(Sht) Then CreateChart = False: Exit Function
```

Currently I have a little bit of each practice scattered throughout the code and I would like to clean it up. Is it best to run this check outside the function or within?

Comment: I would avoid repetitive checks _in main code_ and put it in your `Function` code. It's simplier to maintain - e.g. if you'd like to change logic of your check, consider what would be the easiest: change logic in entire code or in single function?

Comment: In a situation where I have say 4 checks, and I would like to know which issue is causing the problem when the function fails by means of a MsgBox, then sometimes I leave the checks outside of the loops in the main code so that only one notification appears. Is there a way to have the checks within the functions but only report the issues once?

Comment: what you can do is to change return type of your function from `Boolean` to say `Integer` and return `1` when there is no issue, `-1` when code fails on first check, `-2` - when code fails on second check and so on. And in your loop in main code you can add single msgbox for each error "code".

Comment: I am a firm believer that every sub/function should have some type of error handling code. As @simoco says you can return values from your functions to: (a) indicate failure and (b) take a different path. Without traps it's less than fun trying to find the culprit if calls are nested four or five levels deep!

Comment: @WayneG.Dunn, so you are advocating having checks within and without as well?

Comment: I always try to place traps in every function/sub, then have the option of handling there or passing off judgment to the calling routine. If you have Sub1 call Sub2 and that calls Sub3, and an error occurs in Sub3, Sub1 will not know where the error came from unless you communicate that to it. Some people write subroutines that handle all work associated with one task, whereas others make use of reusable code. You need to determine what signals a 'halt! do not proceed!' and place the code to handle that wherever it needs to go.

Answer (score 2):

> I am dealing with code with multiple modules and many situations where certain checks need to be performed before the function can successfully run. Is it most appropriate to put a check within the loop in the Click sub routine, something like:

Generally I would avoid repeating the same check in your main code if you are going to do it for each.

> In a situation where I have say 4 checks, and I would like to know which issue is causing the problem when the function fails by means of a MsgBox, then sometimes I leave the checks outside of the loops in the main code so that only one notification appears. Is there a way to have the checks within the functions but only report the issues once?

It sounds like you have a handful of checks will be the same for each CreateChart method. I would do something like:

```
Sub mainSub()
    If validateCreateChart Then
        CreateChart
    End If
End Sub

Sub CreateChart()
    On Error Goto errHandler
    'do stuff
    exit sub
    errHandler:
        msgbox  "Unexpected error: " & err.description
End Sub

Function validateCreateChart() As Boolean


    If ConditionOne Then
        validateCreateChart = False
        MsgBox "error condition 1"
        Exit Function
    End If


    If ConditionTwo Then
        validateCreateChart = False
        MsgBox "error condition 2"
        Exit Function
    End If

    'etc

End Function
```

You don't want to have your logic for errors/prompts scattered everywhere. Especially if you are doing the same checks and will have the same error prompts for each of them.

Don't leave a sub/function without some error handling or you will find yourself regretting it when some "this will never happen" circumstance happens.

Comment: I like this solution. I've got to untangle the web before I can get everything together, but this should work.

Comment: @teepee I have started switching all my checks to be this format. Otherwise, inevitably, I end up with multiple "almost the same but not" sequences of checks. And let me tell you it's a pain when you have to update them :)  You might find [reading on DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself) relevant.